# Cuál es la etimología de "tolai"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa, insultos

[*Tolai*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hwFnDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT303&lpg=PT303&dq=tolai+idiota) se usa en el sur de España como jerga para "tonto, idiota". Pero cuál es su etimología?

Comment: [La RAE incluirá las palabras Tolai y Truja en la nueva edición del diccionario](http://es.globedia.com/rae-incluira-palabras-tolai-truja-edicion-diccionario): "La primera [tolai] nace en los barrios bajos de las ciudades del mediterráneo sur español. Su significado, de sobra conocido por todos, se refiere a personas con escasas aptitudes." Pero no se explica realmente el origen del término

Comment: @Diego y lo curioso es que ese artículo es de 2011, y la RAE no ha incluido la palabra "tolai" en el diccionario...

Comment: Tanto el _Zerolo_ (1895) como una ficha del _Fichero General_ dicen que "tolai" es un tipo de liebre de Asia, pero no creo que tenga nada que ver.

Comment: Tolai, tribu de Nueva Guinea, usan conchas de molusco llamadas camela como moneda. Quizás tenga algo que ver, aunque son ellos quienes las recolectan y venden, osea que tolais tolais no serán, son ellos los que camelan a otros

Answer (score 2):

En Coreano existe la palabra "Torai" que se pronuncia parecido y se traduce como "tonto" de forma coloquial. Dudo que venga de ahí la etimología de nuestro "Tolai", pero me hizo gracia la coincidencia.

Answer (score 2):

**Origen de tolai**

Tras investigar y rastrear en múltiples fuentes, no he logrado ver con claridad la etimología de esta expresión. En cualquier caso, parece plenamente aceptado que **tolai** proviene del caló, y en ese sentido puede considerarse un *gitanismo* (DLE: “Vocablo o giro propio de la lengua que hablan los gitanos”).

Sin embargo, no queda clara su etimología, que aún está sujeta a presunciones o especulaciones.

En mi búsqueda, sí he podido ver algunas cuestiones de interés, que quiero compartir con todos.

---

En su *Inventario general de insultos*, **Pancracio Celdrán** no recoge **tolai**, y sí las formas **tolai**, **tolili**, y **toli-toli**.

---

La forma *tolili* la utiliza el gran **Enrique Jardiel Poncela** en su novela *¡Espérame en Siberia, vida mía!* (1930). La frase literal dice "¡Tolili! ¡Más que tolili!", y el propio autor, en una nota a pie de página apunta "Tolili: tonto en esperanto".

---

Ramoncín, en su ya clásico **Tocho cheli** (1993) ya recogía las formas:

- **tolai**. Gilipollas, imbécil, toli.
- **toli**. 1. Tolai, tolili, imbécil, estulto. // 2. Víctima.
- **tolili**. Tolai, toli, idiota, imbécil, gilipollas.

---

En el *Diccionario del Argot. El Sohez*, de **Delfín Carbonell Basset**, no aparece tolai, pero sí **tolili**.

---

**Tolai con y (tolay)**

Llamativa, al menos, resulta la forma escrita con "y" que utilizan algunos periodistas o columnistas, como el artículo titulado precisamente [*Tolay*, escrito por Rosa Belmonte en el diario *Las Provincias*](https://www.lasprovincias.es/comunitat/opinion/tolay-20180426002326-ntvo.html).

O este [otro artículo, con el mismo título, publicado en el *Diario de Cádiz*](https://www.diariodecadiz.es/opinion/analisis/Tolay_0_1239776143.html).

Answer (score 2):

En gallego se ha usado siempre la palabra "**tolai**" como derivación del término "**tolo**" que en gallego tiene el significado de "*loco*" o "*tonto*".

Answer (score 1):

Ni idea tiene la RAE (lo digo bromeando). Tolai seguro que deriva del gallego, con raices latinas mas puras que el castellano. Tolo=loco.
Ojalá los políticos se dejasen de "actualizar" las distintas lenguas regionales...

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].